# Gorm change primary key, not found with id null

Tags: grails, grails-orm, scaffolding, natural-key

I have read tons of questions about this and it seems that nobody gets it to work.

I am using grails, and I am creating a class that doesn't have id as the primary key.

I get the message "usuario not found with id null". this is the code of my domain class:

```
    class Usuario implements Serializable{ 

     String nombre 
     String celular 
     String telefono 
     String apellido 
     String password 
     String nick 

     static mapping = { 
      table 'Usuarios' 
      version false 
      id composite: ['nick'] 
} 
}
```

I also tried the normal way with the:

```
    static mapping = { 
    table 'Usuarios' 
    version false 
     id name: 'nick' 
}
```

It actually maps the table the way I want to with the natural key and everything, it inserts the new usuarios, but the gui is incapable of retrieving any objects and shows the error: "usuario not found with id null"

I tried to modify the show(Long id) method, but it wont help either, this is my show method from the controller:

```
    def show(String nick) {
    def usuarioInstance = Usuario.get(nick)
    if (!usuarioInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'usuario.label', default: 'Usuario'), nick])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [usuarioInstance: usuarioInstance]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the **assigned** generator:

```
static mapping = {
    ...
    id column: 'nick', generator: 'assigned'
}
```

Plus it might be wise to add the following constraints:

```
static constraints = {
    nick blank:false, nullable:false, unique: true
}
```

Comment: i assigned the generator too, it still gives me the same error. i mean, it inserts the new "usuario", but it won't retrieve it. it still gives the same "usuario not found with id null" even though table usuario doesn't have any id property

Comment: It might be that you have to rename your **nick**-property to **id** and: 1) rename mapping & constraints appropriately, 2) create a getter and setter for nick (that manipulates id-field), 3) add **static transients = ['nick']** (to go around the problem of having setter&getter but no field)

Comment: Ok i finally got this to work, the problem was indeed the controller and the views that kept redirecting and calling methods using usuarioInstance.username : my mapping was
         static mapping = {
          table 'Usuario'
          version false 
          id name: 'username', generator: 'assigned'}

Comment: And i changed the method "show" on the controller see code below:
def show(String id) { def usuarioInstance=Usuario.findByUsername(id)
        if (!usuarioInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'usuario.label', default: 'Usuario'), id])
            redirect(action: "list")
            return
        }

        [usuarioInstance: usuarioInstance]
    }

Comment: If anyone wants more information about how to get this to work can pm me, ill help anyone